# Proving a function $f(m,n)$ which satisfies two conditions is a constant

Tags: number-theory, functions

I found the following question in a book only with one sentence. "This question can be solved by an elementary way. Note that the following two are false: (1) If a function is bounded from below, then it has minimum value. (2) A monotone decreasing sequence reaches a negative value."

**Question**: Let $m,n$ be integers. Supposing that a function $f(m,n)$ defined by $m,n$ satisfies the following two conditions, then prove that $f(m,n)$ is a constant.

*1.* $f(m,n)\ge0$.

*2.* $4f(m,n)=f(m-1,n)+f(m+1,n)+f(m,n-1)+f(m,n+1)$.

I suspect this question can be solved by a geometric aspect. I've tried to prove this, but I'm facing difficulty. Could you show me how to prove this?

Comment: It is a discrete version of Laplace equation
$\nabla^{2}\Phi = 0$ which leads to $\int\Psi\nabla^{2}\Psi\,{\rm d}V = 0$ and to
$\int\left\vert\nabla\Psi\right\vert^{2} = 0$ which involves an integration by parts. The discrete version requires "Abel Summations by part" identity (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts ).

Comment: Where did you get this problem? It feels familiar to me for some reason.

Comment: @mixedmath: I found this in the book which a friend of mine has, but I don't know its name. I'll ask him.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Thank you for nice information.

Comment: @mathlove You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probabilistic proof is given at the bottom of [this page](http://everything2.com/title/Z%255En+admits+no+bounded+harmonic+function).